# Problem: changing EPSG projections leads to different spatial merge results

Tags: python, geopandas, spatial-join

I am using python/geopandas to merge two datasets - one from WRI Aqueduct Global Flood Risk containing river basins info and one containing a list of real estate properties with lat and long I want to. The two datasets have both EPSG 4326 coordinate systems, but in order to create a buffer (in mt) around the real estate properties, I changed both projections to EPSG 3006 and create a buffer of 10 KM for the assets.

I was surprised to see that when I merge the two files in the EPSG 3006 coordinate systems I only get two inner merges while when I merge them using EPSG 4326 (I don't set any buffer) all my assets are merged with river basins.

What could be the problem? Below is the code I am using:

For EPSG 3006

```
rfd = r"C:\Users\~\aqueduct_global_flood_risk_data_by_river_basin_20150304.shp"
wri_rfr = gpd.read_file(rfd, crs='epsg:4326')

##Geographic Data (Lat and Long)
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\~\Data.csv')
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df['Longitude'], df['Latitude']))
gdf = gdf.set_crs('epsg:4326')

gdf = gdf.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3006'})
gdf.geometry = gdf.geometry.buffer(10000)
gdf = gdf.loc[gdf.is_valid]
wri_rfr_3006  = wri_rfr.to_crs({'init': 'epsg:3006'})
wri_rfr_3006  =  wri_rfr_3006.loc[wri_rfr_3006.is_valid]

river_basin_events = gpd.sjoin(gdf, wri_rfr_3006, how='inner')
river_basin_events
```

and with EPSG 4326 coordinates

```
rfd = r"C:\Users\~\aqueduct_global_flood_risk_data_by_river_basin_20150304.shp"
wri_rfr = gpd.read_file(rfd, crs='epsg:4326')

##Geographic Data (Lat and Long)
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\~\Data.csv')
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df['Longitude'], df['Latitude']))
gdf = gdf.set_crs('epsg:4326')
  
river_basin_events = gpd.sjoin(gdf, wri_rfr, how='inner')
river_basin_events
```

Comment: geospatial ```merge``` is not ```sjoin```. ```sjoin``` is joining attributes based on spatial parameters; for instance, join the 2 dataframe attributes if they overlap. have you looked at ```overlay``` function in ```geopandas```?

Comment: My goal is to look at what assets fall within the boundaries of the river basins - I assume this is what geopandas sjojn() delivers?

Comment: sounds like much more optimised with ```overlay``` with ```intersection``` relationship. [check this](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/user_guide/set_operations.html).

Comment: it's a shapefile, why do you have ```crs='epsg:4326'``` parameter in ```wri_rfr = gpd.read_file(rfd, crs='epsg:4326')```?

Comment: should I not declare the projections system for a shapefile containing geographical info? Also I checked, epsg:4326 is the coordination system for WRI dataset.